# The generated query by EF Core runs very slow in some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, entity-framework-core

We are using EF core in our application

In one of the Services, the EF core generates the below TSQL and runs. but it is prolonged!

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [di].[Id] AS [Key], [di].[Code], [di].[DocumentTypeRef], [di].[IsActive], [di].[IsVisible], [di].[IsGlobal], [di].[IsPrintable], [di].[RecordPrefix], [di].[Owner_PersonRef], [owner].[FullName] AS [DocumentInfoOwnerFullName], [dil].[_Title] AS [ThisIsA_Title], [dil].[_Description] AS [_Description0], [docw].[WorkbenchRef], [t].[_Title] AS [_WorkbenchTitle], [t].[_Description] AS [_WorkbenchDescription], [docc].[CompanyRef], [cl].[_Title] AS [_CompanyTitle], [dt].[IsRecordable] AS [DocumentTypeIsRecordable], [dt].[ReviewCycle] AS [DocumentTypeReviewCycle], [dtl].[_Title] AS [_DocumentTypeTitle], [dtl].[_Description] AS [_DocumentTypeDescription], [t0].[Id] AS [DocumentVersionKey], [t0].[Creator_PersonRef] AS [DocumentVersionCreator_PersonRef], [t0].[EffectiveDate] AS [DocumentVersionEffectiveDate], [t0].[ExpireDate] AS [DocumentVersionExpireDate], [t0].[IsActive] AS [DocumentVersionIsActive], [t0].[PublishDate] AS [DocumentVersionPublishDate], [t0].[VersionNo] AS [DocumentVersionVersionNo], [t0].[ReviewDate] AS [DocumentVersionReviewDate], [t0].[ItemRowRef_DocVersionState], [t1].[FullName] AS [DocumentVersionCreatorFullName], [t2].[_Title] AS [_DocVersionStateTitle]
FROM [QMS].[DocumentInfo] AS [di]
INNER JOIN [QMS].[DocumentInfoLanguage] AS [dil] ON [di].[Id] = [dil].[DocumentInfoRef]
INNER JOIN [QMS].[DocumentCompany] AS [docc] ON [di].[Id] = [docc].[DocumentInfoRef]
INNER JOIN [HRM].[CompanyLanguage] AS [cl] ON [docc].[CompanyRef] = [cl].[CompanyRef]
INNER JOIN [QMS].[DocumentType] AS [dt] ON [di].[DocumentTypeRef] = [dt].[Id]
INNER JOIN [QMS].[DocumentTypeLanguage] AS [dtl] ON [dt].[Id] = [dtl].[DocumentTypeRef]
INNER JOIN [BAS].[PersonLanguage] AS [owner] ON [di].[Owner_PersonRef] = [owner].[PersonRef]
LEFT JOIN [QMS].[DocumentWorkbench] AS [docw] ON [di].[Id] = [docw].[DocumentInfoRef]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [x].*
    FROM [QMS].[WorkbenchLanguage] AS [x]
    WHERE [x].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_0
) AS [t] ON [docw].[WorkbenchRef] = [t].[WorkbenchRef]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [x0].*
    FROM [QMS].[DocumentVersion] AS [x0]
    WHERE ([x0].[ExpireDate] IS NULL OR ([x0].[ExpireDate] > GETDATE())) AND ([x0].[EffectiveDate] < GETDATE())
) AS [t0] ON [di].[Id] = [t0].[DocumentInfoRef]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [x1].*
    FROM [BAS].[PersonLanguage] AS [x1]
    WHERE [x1].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_1
) AS [t1] ON [t0].[Creator_PersonRef] = [t1].[PersonRef]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [x2].*
    FROM [BAS].[ItemRowLanguage] AS [x2]
    WHERE [x2].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_2
) AS [t2] ON [t0].[ItemRowRef_DocVersionState] = [t2].[ItemRowRef]
WHERE (((((([dil].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_3) AND ([cl].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_4)) AND ([dtl].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_5)) AND ([owner].[LanguageRef] = @__languageRef_6)) 

AND (CHARINDEX(N''we'', [dil].[_Title]) > 0)) 

AND [docc].[CompanyRef] IN (CAST(3 AS smallint))) AND ([di].[IsVisible] = 1)
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
OFFSET @__p_8 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_9 ROWS ONLY',N'@__languageRef_0 int,@__languageRef_1 int,@__languageRef_2 int,@__languageRef_3 int,@__languageRef_4 int,@__languageRef_5 int,@__languageRef_6 int,@__p_8 int,@__p_9 int',@__languageRef_0=1,@__languageRef_1=1,@__languageRef_2=1,@__languageRef_3=1,@__languageRef_4=1,@__languageRef_5=1,@__languageRef_6=1,@__p_8=0,@__p_9=25
```

I got this query from SQL Profiler and tried to run it on SSMS

It ran again, but again it was slow!

I tried to find the problem. after a while I realized when I ignored some portion of the query, the query runs fast! for example when I deleted some of the JOINs, everything runs perfectly, or when I deleted the left hand of WHERE condition, again everything was OK! Even when I replaced the CHARINDEX with LIKE, again! the query ran fast.

I finally realized that the query is only running slowly if these combinations are placed together, which is very strange

It is possible that I am wrong. But no matter how hard I tried, I did not understand the reason for this behavior

Now can anyone help to understand this problem and find a solution for it?

Comment: A query running faster after removing joins is not really strange.  Some adhoc advice: 1) Change the derived left joins to direct left join. 2) We need the execution plan to give you any kind of performance help. Use pastetheplan.com to provide uw with one

Comment: Show LINQ query also.

Comment: I really don't like that AND (CHARINDEX(N''we'', [dil].[_Title]) > 0)) line.  That just smells like clustered index scan to me.

Comment: Are indexes being defined by EF?  EF might be great at some things, but I don't think query optimization is one of them.